# How to pass two array over session and combine them to display

Tags: php

I am trying to send two array over session and then combined them to display together but nothing displayed.This is my code--->

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      function tee($uid){
      include 'connect.php';
      $uid=$uid;
      $parent=array();
      $child=array();
      $_SESSION["child"]=array();
      $_SESSION["parent"]=array();
      $sql="select id from relation2 where parentID=$uid";
      $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
       while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
    $parent[]=$uid;
    $child[]=$row["id"];
    $_SESSION["child"][]=$child;
    $_SESSION["parent"][]=$parent;
   tee($row["id"]);
    }

    }
  tee(2);

    foreach(array_combine($_SESSION["child"],$_SESSION["parent"]) as $child=>$parent)
   {
      echo $child.'----------->'.$parent;
      echo '<br>';
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve ? Why you need them merged ?

Comment: Couple of issues , `include 'connect.php';` shouldn't be called inside the function , Also passing the var `$uid` in this way is a big security issue , Also please consider using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` which has many great features and security enhancements . Finally no need to have two session arrays , One is enough and could be filled up during the recursive function .

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the the query output with something custom and this code worked for me

```
  <?php
      session_start();
      function tee($uid){
          include 'connect.php';
          $parent=array();
          $child=array();
          $_SESSION["child"]=array();
          $_SESSION["parent"]=array();
          $sql="select id from relation2 where parentID=$uid";
          $result=mysqli_query($sql,$link);
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {

            $_SESSION["child"][]=$row["id"];
            $_SESSION["parent"][]=$uid;
          }
      tee(2);

    foreach(array_combine($_SESSION["child"],$_SESSION["parent"]) as $child=>$parent)
    {
      echo $child.'----------->'.$parent;
      echo '<br>';
    }

    ?>
```

Also check the [extract()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.extract.php) function

If you pass `$uid` from user input use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.pdo.php)